# Create custom wordpress admin submenu item from an existing custom menu item that opens an iframe

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Not sure how to layout the question sorry if it was confusing.
I have already used the below code to add a custom link on the admin menu and it opens up an iframe to a map I have created with a plugin.

How can I add a submenu item to this? I grabbed this code from another site and did not create it myself.

```html
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'oa_register_menu_document' );
function oa_register_menu_document() {
    add_menu_page( 'Manual', 'Producers Map', 'manage_options', 'oa-document', 'oa_view_document_page',3);
}
function oa_view_document_page(){
?>
    <div id="poststuff" class="oa-document">
        <div class="postbox  hide-if-js" id="postexcerpt" style="display: block; height: 100vh;">
            <iframe src="https://www.mywebsite.com/producers" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
```

Comment: since you added the main page using `add_menu_page`, you can easily insert a subpage using `add_submenu_page` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/

Answer (score 0):

Top-level menu pages are created using the `add_menu_page()` function, as seen in the code you posted. To create a submenu page, use the related function `add_submenu_page()`.

Example:

```
function oa_register_menu_document() {
    add_menu_page( 'Manual', 'Producers Map', 'manage_options', 'oa-document', 'oa_view_document_page', 3);
    add_submenu_page( 'oa-document', 'My Submenu Page', 'My Submenu Page', 'manage_options', 'oa-document-submenu-page', 'oa_submenu_page' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'oa_register_menu_document' );

function oa_submenu_page() {
    // Output your submenu page content...
}
```

Documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/